# Delete rows based on the dates present in the adjacent rows

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have dates in the fifth column of my sheet.

```
function deleteOldData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastrow = datarange.getLastRow();
  var values = datarange.getValues();

  var currentDate = new Date();
  var daysago = new Date().setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 5);
  daysago = new Date(Date.parse(daysago))
  Logger.log(daysago)


  for (i=lastrow;i>=2;i--) {
var tempdate = sheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
if(tempdate < daysago)  {
      sheet.deleteRows(2, i);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

I am using this code to delete the rows that have dates lesser than 5 days ago from today. It should delete only those rows that has dates less than 5 days ago from today but it is deleting all the rows expect the headers which i have omitted in the code.

the date in my sheet looks like this:

```
7/1/2020 18:28:05
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You need to use `deleteRow()` instead of `deleteRows()`.*

#### More Information:

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowsrowposition,-howmany):

> `deleteRows(rowPosition, howMany)`
>
> Deletes a number of rows starting at the given row position.
>
> ```
> var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
> var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
> // Rows start at "1" - this deletes the first two rows
> sheet.deleteRows(1, 2);
> ```

So when you call `sheet.deleteRows(2, i);` you are deleting multiple rows, starting from row 2, and finishing `i` rows later - which could potentially be as high as `lastrow`.

#### Code Modification:

You also do not need to use the `break` keyword - this is going to stop the whole loop once the `if` condition is met the first time, and not continue to delete all rows where the day is more than five days ago.

I also cleaned up the function a little:

- As you already get the data from the sheet and store it in `values`, you do not need to get the data again for `tempdate` - you can just assign it straight from the `values` array.
- To make the date comparisons more precise, the exact timestamps can be extracted from the date objects rather than working with things like `getDate() - 5` etc:

```js
function deleteOldData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastrow = datarange.getLastRow();
  var values = datarange.getValues();
  
  var currentDate = new Date().getTime();
  var daysago = (new Date().getTime() - 432000000);
    
  for (var i = lastrow; i > 1; i--) {
    var tempdate = values[i - 1][4];
 
    if((new Date(tempdate).getTime()) < daysago)  {
      sheet.deleteRow(i);
    }
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [Class Sheet - `deleteRow(position)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowrowposition)
- [Class Sheet - `deleteRows(position, howMany)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowsrowposition,-howmany)

Comment: what is 432000000?

Comment: `.getTime()` converts the Date to milliseconds - 432000000 is the number of milliseconds in 5 days :)